# css: <img> position with given coords x,y  on top of another image (using jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, coordinates

I have the following problem and I'm pretty bad at CSS, 
but good at Javascript and Jquery 
I have a map (JPG size 579x527)  and some coordinates points that represent some points on the map
can be represented with a simple circle icon

I must put those points with some links as layers on top of the image map
I thought that by doing margin -X and then puting left:X will solve the problem but it's not like that
Here's my code so far (I'm generating the coords randomly with 20 points)

```
function randomFromTo(from, to){
       return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
    }

jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
var tmp;
var x;
var y;
var x_margin;
var y_margin;

for(var i=0;i<=20;i++) {
tmp=jQuery('#img_map').html(); //the map itself



x=randomFromTo(10,500);
y=randomFromTo(10,500);

jQuery('#img_map').html(tmp+'<a href="#" style="display:block;position:relative;margin-left:-'+x+'px; margin-top:-'+y+'px;left:'+x+'px; top:'+y+'px; "><img src="icon_point.png" border="0" width="20" height="20"></a>');

}

});
```

The code doesn't work ...it shows wierd the points..

Comment: Put some html here whch are used with this script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `position:absolute; left:250px; top:250px;` instead of margin

```
jQuery('#img_map').html(tmp+'<a href="#" style="display:block;position:absolute;left:-'+x+'px; top:-'+y+'px;"><img src="icon_point.png" border="0" width="20" height="20"></a>');
```

and the parent element needs to have `position:relative;`

Comment: can't do absolute, I have a centered div on the page..
this image is on the content div and doesn't start from 0,0 of the page
I have to get the absolute position of the img, then add the x,y of the points...but what happends if the user resizes the page..the points will not be scroll...

Comment: Thats why you need to add position:relative; to the parent element then the position:absolute will work from that elements position;) so it will be locked to the parent element

Comment: ok, I think I didn´t understood position:absolute eighter.. It works :) I thought that absolute was refering to the 0,0 coords of the page

Comment: @PartySoft, `position:absolute` refers to the closest **positioned** ancestor. look at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#positioning-scheme

Answer (score 1):

Use relative positioning inside the map. Here is sample:

**html**

```
<div id="img_map"></div>
```

**css**

```
#img_map { background:red; position:relative; width:500px; height:500px; }
.point { display:block; background:green; width:20px; height:20px; position:absolute; }
```

**script**

```
function randomFromTo(from, to){
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
    var $map = jQuery('#img_map');
    for(var i=0;i<=20;i++) {

        var x = randomFromTo(10,500);
        var y = randomFromTo(10,500);

        var $point = jQuery('<a href="#" class="point"><img src="icon_point.png" /></a>').css({top:y + 'px', left:x + 'px'});
        $map.append($point); 

    }
});
```

**Working sample**: http://jsfiddle.net/8yqpy/11/